# Pandas: reshaping and multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have a pandas dataframe with these columns:

- itemid
- 15/01/2015 status
- 15/01/2015 location
- 15/02/2015 status
- 15/02/2015 location
- etc.

How can I do these two things ?

1. create multi-indexed columns, where the first index is the month, and the second index is the metric I am tracking (status, location)
2. stack the colum so that the table looks something like this:

```html
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+--+
| itemid |  mymonth  | location | status |  |
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+--+
| A      | 15/1/2015 | North    | Good   |  |
| A      | 15/2/2015 | South    | Bad    |  |
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+--+
```

starting from an input that looks like this:

```
+--------+-------------------+---------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| itemid | 15/01/2015 status | 15/01/2015 location | 15/02/2015 status | 15/02/2015 location |
+--------+-------------------+---------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| A      | Good              | North               | Bad               | South               |
+--------+-------------------+---------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

which (the input) can be recreated with:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['itemid']=['A']
df['15/01/2015 status'] = ['Good']
df['15/01/2015 location'] = ['North']
df['15/02/2015 status'] = ['Bad']
df['15/02/2015 location'] = ['South']
```

I have been thinking about how to use melt, but I'm not too sure if it would work in this context.

Comment: Can you add sample of input DataFrame which can create desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and last [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
df1 = df.set_index('itemid').stack().reset_index()
df1.columns = ['itemid','mymonth', 'd']

df1[['mymonth','c']] = df1.mymonth.str.split('\s+').apply(pd.Series)
print df1
  itemid     mymonth      d         c
0      A  15/01/2015   Good    status
1      A  15/01/2015  North  location
2      A  15/02/2015    Bad    status
3      A  15/02/2015  South  location

print df1.pivot_table(index=['itemid', 'mymonth'], columns='c', values='d', aggfunc='first')
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)

  itemid     mymonth location status
0      A  15/01/2015    North   Good
1      A  15/02/2015    South    Bad
```

EDIT:

I think if aggregating by `first` you can sometimes lost data, because you bring only first value (if duplicity in columns creating new index) and other values are lost.

So if aggregating by strings, you can use `join`. Data are **NOT** lost, only are joined and separated by `,`:

```
print df1.pivot_table(index=['itemid', 'mymonth'], columns='c', values='d',aggfunc=', '.join)
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Comment: You're a star! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you for accepting. I add next solution - I was afraid because you can potencially lost data. Please check it and if something is not clear, I can try explain better.

Comment: Thanks. In the specific cases I am working on it's not an issue, luckily, because the data is such that there are no duplicates.